# What does “a nougat fireguard” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

He makes me miss the relative jocundity of King Joffrey killing sex workers with a cross-bow. Pleasingly, we saw in this opening episode that Ramsay’s father Rouse is now fully aware that his son is as much use as a nougat fireguard when it comes to leadership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Game of Thrones, so I assume that "fireguard" does not have a special meaning in the realm of Game of Thrones. *Fireguard* refers to one of these guards/screens
[image]

I believe that the purpose of the guard is to prevent  burning logs from rolling away and starting fires in case they fall out of a stove, fireplace, etc.

*Nougat* refers to

> [nougat](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nougat)
>   A confection made from a sugar or honey paste into which nuts are mixed.

[image]

So a *nougat fireguard* means a fireguard *made out of* nougat. You can imagine that a nougat fireguard would be **useless**. So the author is saying that the son is useless/ineffective as a leader.

Comment: Can I "+2" because of the images?